how to change json data then encode using php
I am pulling in a json file and I change one nested nodes values into to one value sepeated with |'s. Then encode and save file.
How can I achieve this using php?
My Json looks like this,
{
    "list": [
        {
            "Id": 398,
            "Product Title": "Banner",
            "Sku": "vb-13oz",
            "Short Description": "text",
            "Long Description": "text",
            "Cost": "0.95",
            "Price": "3.25",
            "Category": [{ "Id": 9, "Title": "Banners" }],
            "Attribute Sides": [{ "Id": 1, "Title": "1 Side" }],
            "Attribute Grommets": [
                { "Id": 1, "Title": "Every 2' All Sides" },
                { "Id": 2, "Title": "Every 2' Top and Bottom" },
                { "Id": 3, "Title": "Every 2' Left & Right" },
                { "Id": 4, "Title": "4 Corners Only" },
                { "Id": 5, "Title": "No Gromments" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

and this is what I am expecting my output to be.
{
    "list": [
        {
            "Id": 398,
            "Product Title": "Banner",
            "Sku": "vb-13oz",
            "Short Description": "text",
            "Long Description": "text",
            "Cost": "0.95",
            "Price": "3.25",
            "Category": [{ "Id": 9, "Title": "Banners" }],
            "Attribute Sides": [{ "Id": 1, "Title": "1 Side" }],
            "Attribute Grommets": [
                 { "Id": 1, "Title": "Every 2' All Sides | Every 2' Top and Bottom | Every 2' Left & Right | 4 Corners Only | No Gromments" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


Here is what I have
 file_put_contents("importfiles/importproducts1.json", $response);

  //tweak output
  $json_object = file_get_contents('importfiles/importproducts1.json');
  $data = json_decode($json_object, true);

  $data['some_key'] = "some_value";  //What goes here ?

  $json_object = json_encode($data);
  file_put_contents('importfiles/importproducts.json', $json_object);


Use explode() to split the value of $data['list'][0]['Attribute Grommets'][0]. Loop over that creating the new array you want, and assign that array back to $data['list'][0]['Attribute Grommets'].

Loop over list, and for each item, overwrite the Attribute Grommets array with a new array, into which you put the first Id, and the titles extracted from the full array using array_column, imploded with your desired separator.
foreach($data['list'] as $key => $item) {
    $data['list'][$key]['Attribute Grommets'] = [
        [
            'Id' => $item['Attribute Grommets'][0]['Id'],
            'Title' => implode(' | ', array_column($item['Attribute Grommets'], 'Title'))
        ]
    ];
}

https://3v4l.org/rSHmM
